# Liquibase inserts wrong default date value into MySql

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I have changelog:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.0.xsd">
    <changeSet  id="10" author="vaa25">
        <createTable tableName="test" schemaName="liquibase">
            <column name="id" type="INT" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="created_at" type="DATETIME(3)" defaultValueDate="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Result of execution:
`liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid default value for 'created_at' [Failed SQL: (1067) CREATE TABLE liquibase.test (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, created_at datetime(3) DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY (id))]`

Cause: liquibase substitutes NOW() instead NOW(3).

Yes, of course I can apply 'sql' tag with correct native sql script, but anyway seems it is liquibase bug.  Liquibase 4.0.0 and Mysql 8.0.15 used.

This is more bug report then question.

Comment: Is `DATETIME(3)` a valid data type? Shouldn't it just be `type="DATETIME"`?

Comment: Yes, it is valid data type. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html

`An optional fsp value in the range from 0 to 6 may be given to specify fractional seconds precision. A value of 0 signifies that there is no fractional part. If omitted, the default precision is 0.`

Comment: If this is a liquibase bug (and it sounds like it), StackOverflow is not the right place, please consider closing this Question and log the issue in the liquibase issue tracker: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues